# Is it possible to use GNU Scientific Library in Swift (under Linux)?

Tags: linux, swift, gsl

I couldn't find any material regarding using gnu scientific library in swift under Linux. Is it possible? If so, then how?

For example, I am interested in generating random numbers with normal distribution with `gsl_ran_gaussian`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using, for example, system modules.  See this question: [Use a C library in Swift on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131110/use-a-c-library-in-swift-on-linux/34667252#34667252)

Yet another approach is in answers to this question: [Compile C code and expose it to Swift under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570497/compile-c-code-and-expose-it-to-swift-under-linux/36637270#36637270)

If you want to use only a small subset of the API, then you might save some effort by writing a C wrapper around the needed functionality and calling that wrapper from Swift.